# which situation use list<tablename> and tablename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I am confused about which situation use `public List<StudentViewModal> sm { get; set; }` and `public student stud { get; set; }` ??

I create a table which name is student table and then create a ViewModel which name is StudentViewModal

student

```
    public class student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
```

StudentViewModal

```
    public class StudentViewModal
    {
        public List<StudentViewModal> sm { get; set; }
        public student stud { get; set; }
    }
```

and then I create a home controller

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //here get the data from the database and display in the data table
        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //here I am performing insert update delete
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**and then after creating an IndexView**

```
@model ListVsTable.Models.StudentViewModal     //here I am performing sorting, searching in datatable? can I use here StudentViewModal for sorting, searching in the data table???     
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

**and then after creating a CreateView**

```
@model ListVsTable.Models.student       //here I am performing insert, update, delete operation? can I use here student table for insert update delete???  

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
```

I am stuck on which situation use

**ViewModel**

```
public List<StudentViewModal> sm { get; set; }
```

and

**table**

```
 public student stud { get; set; }
```

I am a student please help

**which situation use student table only and StudentViewModal only**

need help

Comment: Use a list in a view where you want to display data about many students. Use a single object when the view only deals with one student

Comment: @ADyson still some confusion single object means single table am I right? can you explain in detail so my dough is clear

Comment: A single _instance_ of an object would represent one row in your table. A list of objects would represent multiple rows in your table. You also seem to be a bit confused between viewmodel objects and objects which represent your tables directly. Have you studied any of the official MVC tutorials provided by Microsoft?